# Add rewrite rule in plugin: with .htaccess in plugin folder or using WordPress functions

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, wordpress

I need add a rewrite rule in my plugin, and distribute it with my code. All works fine if I put the rule in the .htaccess in the WordPress root folder, but I need distribute the plugin with my rule.

I try to put a .htaccess inside the plugin folder and try to use the [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) function but doesn't works either.

Here the .htaccess code that works correctly in WordPress root folder but doesn't works in my plugin folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule my-plugin/pages/tp(.*)\.php$ wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/pages/request.php?pid=$1

</IfModule>
```

I try the follow code in my plugin but doesn't works either:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars' );
function add_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'pid';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_init' );
function add_init()
{
    $plugin_url = 'the-path-to-my-plugin-folder';
    add_rewrite_rule('my-plugin/pages/tp(.*)\.php'
                  , $plugin_url . 'pages/request.php?pid=$matches[1]','top');

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rewrite_rules(); // I know this should be called only one time, but I put it here just to keep simple the sample code
}
```

But I always get the error that the URL wasn't found.
What I'm doing wrong? How can I do what I need? I searched for similar questions but none solve my problem.

My plugin folder structure is:

Main folder: /wp-content/plugins/my-plugin
------ /pages (sub folder)
-------------/request.php (script that should receive the request)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NOTE: WordPress Rewrite API is not the same as Apache Rewrite module.
>   WP Rewrite API doesn't redirect a request to another URL, it used to
>   parse current URL and fill `query_vars` array.

The issue is in the second parameter of you `add_rewrite_rule` function call. It has to start from `index.php?` and then there should be your arguments, like `pid`, for example:

```
"index.php?pid=$matches[1]...."
```

So your `add_init` function should be like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse8170_add_init' );
function wpse8170_add_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('my-plugin/pages/tp(.*)\.php', 'index.php?pid=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Don't forget to flush rewrite rules by visiting `Settings` » `Permalinks` page.

Further reading:

- [The Rewrite API: The Basics](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-the-basics/)
- [The Rewrite API: Post Types & Taxonomies](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-post-types-taxonomies/)

Comment: +1 @Eugene You are right. I was trying to give an example for the function and ended up giving one for the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1):

WP handles the plugins from the `/wp-admin` directory with a PHP script (admin.php), like this:

```
http://MyWP.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=MyPlugin/module.php
```

Therefore, .htaccess files in the plugin directory are not parsed when the plugin is called. They have to be placed in the `wp-admin` directory or in the root directory, as you already found out.

Although copying the .htacces file to the root directory when the plugin is installed -and deleting it when it is removed- is possible, I don't think it is the best option. Having .htaccess files in the WP space doesn't seem like a good idea.

Your second approach looks much better: Creating rewrite rules in the main script.

Looking at your code, I think the problem are the *pattern* (Incoming URL string to match) and possibly the substitution URL path ($plugin_url in your question).

The `$rule` parameter in the `add_rewrite_rule()` function should capture a segment of the URL (Above) used to call the plugin's modules.

I can't suggest anything else because you don't supply enough information about the plugin and it's directory tree, except what can be guessed from the regex in the rewrite rule. But, this is a general idea of a way to achieve what you need.

Comment: thanks, I updated the question with the information you say is missing. The rewrite rule in the .htaccess works correctly, do you mention is a pattern problem but I think you refers to the rule I pass to the WordPress function? Which is the correct pattern?

Comment: @gsc-leticia Agree. The rule you pass to the function is a *pattern* that should match a segment of the URL generated by the admin.php script to call the plugin. I am not sure if the existing one (`my-plugin/pages/tp(.*)\.php`) does it. To see the URL, just check the browser's address bar when the plugin is called and try to match it with the $rule parameter in your script.

Comment: Well, glad you got the correct answer. That's the code I could not figure out as Eugene did.

Comment: Indeed the redirection to my script page (inside my plugin) can't be done, so I need to use .htaccess in WordPress root folder. But well, at least now I know that I can't ;)