# Update permalinks if not set at the time of plugin activation

Tags: php, wordpress

I need permalink to be set different from default after the plugin is activated 
I used get_option('permalink_structure') to check if permalink already set or not...

Here is the code block used in plugin activation function , I used class structure

```
 if (get_option('permalink_structure'))
    {
        $this->setRewriteRules();
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
    }
```

and here is the serRewriteRules function

```
function setRewriteRules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('plugin-url/$', '/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/page.php', 'top');
}
```

I searched a lot and update my code so many time but still not working for me ....

Comment: I think this answer will help you: [Add rewrite rule in plugin: with .htaccess in plugin folder or using WordPress functions][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619333/add-rewrite-rule-in-plugin-with-htaccess-in-plugin-folder-or-using-wordpress-f

Comment: @Ebola Thanks for your reply ... but i already tries this not work for me .. i can use wp-admin > settings> permalinks to flush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than changing permalink dynamically you can use generate link from WP permalinks function

for e.g.

```
get_the_permalink()
the_permalink()
get_post_type_archive_link()
```